# osgi-karaf-multiple versions of service and camel route

Tags: java, osgi, apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

One of the benefits of OSGi is **Versioning** as [explained here](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/WhyOSGi). As per the documentation, OSGi can host different versions of "same jar" and let the other applications access them accordingly.

I have been given a task to leverage the same properties of OSGi (I am using **Apache-Karaf** container) using Camel routes.

I have to deploy multiple versions of a *service* and have **Camel**, ***route*** to the proper one based on the request. I extensively searched google but I haven't found a suitable example :(

Please throw me any pointers or guide me to an example.

**Update**

By *service*, I mean osgi bundle service which is defined like this

```
  <osgi:service ref="transformService">
        <osgi:interfaces>
            <value>demo.service.TransformService</value>
        </osgi:interfaces>
  </osgi:service>
```

I have followed the steps provided in [this tutorial](https://camel.apache.org/tutorial-osgi-camel-part1.html) to create a service called `transformService` and `TransformServiceImpl` is the implementation class for this service.

Now let's say I will modify `TransformServiceImpl` and release it as new version (by updating my version in `pom.xml`). Also, I will install both the versions, that is,  `demo.service-0.1.jar` and `demo.service-0.2.jar` in **Karaf** (which is OK with Karaf). In this case how can I route to a particular version of service ?

Can I create 2 `osgi:reference` which points to same service but different versions? Something like this?

```
 <osgi:reference id="myTransformV0.1" version="0.1" interface="demo.service.TransformService"/>
 <osgi:reference id="myTransformV0.2" version="0.2" interface="demo.service.TransformService"/>
```

And use them in routes?

```
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
      <from uri="timer://myTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10000"/>
         <choice>
                <when ...> <bean ref="myTransformV0.1" method="transform"/>
                <otherwise> <bean ref="myTransformV0.2" method="transform"/>
         </choice>
      <to uri="log:ExampleRouter"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

Comment: Can you put a queue in the middle and push your message to the queue with a property on it stating what version you need to handle it?  Then you could create a subscriber for each version that applied a filter to each message so that they only processed messages for their version?  I am not sure if you are running in Fuse or have a A-MQ easily available

Answer (score 1):

OSGi versioning is different from the Service versioning. I think the key question is how can you access these camel route with different version.

If your camel route provides RESTful service, it could be easy to provide different version by using different url, such as "/service/v1", "/service/v2". But it is not same with the OSGi versioning, you still need to do some work to fill the gap.

Comment: Thank you @WillemJiang for your response. What I meant by services is osgi bundle service. I have updated the question. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I'm not sure if osgi:reference support version, but if you are using blueprint, you can define a filter which specify the version  that the service could expose.

Comment: Thanks again :) .. osgi:reference does not support version, I put that just for the sake of question. I will explore blueprint..